# How to check if a string is a character in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a textField (`symbolTextField`), I will input character to the textField. And only characters will be accepted in the textField. So I need to check if the input has a single character in the textField.
I have a button, I am updating the button state, when the symbolTextField has only one character instead of several characters (String), then the button will be enabled.
I am thinking about to add one more condition in the "saveButton.isEnabled = " to check if `symbolTextField.text` is a character, how can I do that?

```
func updateSaveButtonState() {
   let symbolText = symbolTextField.text ?? ""
   let nameText = nameTextField.text ?? ""
   let descriptionText = descriptionTextField.text ?? ""
   let usageText = usageTextField.text ?? ""
   saveButton.isEnabled = !symbolText.isEmpty && !nameText.isEmpty && !descriptionText.isEmpty && !usageText.isEmpty
}
```

Comment: character mean ? one element or from specific character set

Comment: Just check that the length of the string is 1, `symbolText.count == 1` if what you mean is that the field should only contain one character.

Comment: It would be better to subclass UItextField and limit its length to one character https://stackoverflow.com/a/37366850/2303865

Comment: character, like “a”, “”, are both a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *is a character* means *is **one** character* just `count` the characters

By the way `UITextField` has a `hasText` property which reduces the code considerably.

```
func updateSaveButtonState() {
   saveButton.isEnabled = nameTextField.hasText && 
                          descriptionText.hasText &&
                          usageTextField.hasText && 
                          symbolTextField.text!.count == 1
}
```

Comment: "UITextField has a hasText property" this is not true. `UITextField` conforms to `UITextInput` which inherits from `UIKeyInput` which contains that property

Comment: Leo, this is nitpicking. Practically `UITextField` **has** this property.

Comment: If someone looks for it at UITextField documentation they will not find it

Comment: wow, .count==1, resolved my confusion, i even spent several hours on it. i focused on the Character() to check the type of the string instance, and no results. i tried extension string to give a computed properties and also failed. but .count = 1, this is a very good validation condition to make sure the input is a character.